# Gradle - only one file include jar in multiplefile

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am using Gradle 2.2.1
in the src/main/java directories, there are a.java,b.java.c.java files
i want to jar, only include a.java file
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
jar {
   includes = ['**/a.class']
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/28214934) a working example can be found.

Comment: thanks, but i tried it, build / libs / exam.jar had only contains the MANIFEST.MF file

Comment: Sure, should be `*.class` of course. If it works, please accept.